# How to prevent same coupon code assignment to multiple email addresses in SFMC using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, api, cloudpage, upsert

**Current use-case / scenario:**

We have a cloud page that is used as an API endpoint. Within the cloud page, there is an Ampscript

```
set @coupon_Code = Lookup("Coupon_DE","Coupon_Code","emailaddress",@ts_subkey,"offer_type",requestparameter("offer_type"))

IF EMPTY(@coupon_Code) THEN


 set @rowset = LOOKUPROWS("Coupon_DE","offer_type",requestparameter("offer_type"), "IsClaimed", "False")

 if ROWCOUNT(@rowset) > 0 THEN
 set @row = row(@Rowset,1)
 set @coupon_Code = Field(@row, "Coupon_Code")

 UpsertDE("Coupon_DE",1,"Coupon_Code", @coupon_Code, "IsClaimed","True","Emailaddress",@ts_subkey)
 ENDIF
```

The cloud page is triggered on a button click on the website after a customer enters an email address that is passed to this cloud page.

**Issue:** If multiple customers (with different email addresses) enters their email addresses and click on the button 1 or 2 seconds apart, the ampscript end up assigning / claiming same coupon code to multiple email address while it should be unique (1 coupon code / per email address).

**Question:** Is there any way to prevent this duplicate / same coupon code assignment and make sure  each marked / claimed code is unique to each email address assigned?

**UPDATE:**

As per the recommendation, I have updated the solution and implemented the ClaimRow and need some assistance.

Currently, the Coupon_DE coupon table looks like this:

**Fields:**
coupon_code
offer_type
emailaddress
timestamp (default value - current date)
isClaimed (boolean - default value "false)

The goal is to assign / claim 1 coupon code / per offer_type

**For example:**
Customer 1 with emailaddress "test@test.com" can get offer

- coupon_code "101" from "offer_type" A
- coupon_code "101" from "offer_type" B
- coupon_code "101" from "offer_type" C and so on...

But within one offer_type, a customer can only claim one unique coupon_code

I have added this logic

```
 set @coupon_Code = Lookup("Coupon_DE","Coupon_Code","emailaddress",@ts_subkey,"offer_type",requestparameter("offer_type"))
    
    IF EMPTY(@coupon_Code) THEN

IF EMPTY(@coupon_Code) THEN

SET @CouponRow = ClaimRow('Coupon_DE', 'IsClaimed', 'offer_type', requestparameter("offer_type"))
 set @couponCode = Field(@couponRow, "coupon_code")


ENDIF
```

**But, coupon code is NOT being assigned. Any issue with my logic?**

Comment: Have you looked into the ClaimRow function? https://ampscript.guide/claimrow/

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj I have and what I am trying to understand if that isn;t this issue is going to be with claimrow as well? UpsertDE is adding email address to Coupon_DE where unique coupons are being stored and marking the unique code row as "IsClaimed". Isn't ClaimRow going to do the same thing?

Comment: Considering the issue here is more due to multiple calls triggering the code at exact same second. Is ClaimRow now going to work same as UpsertDE when triggered at exact second?

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the issue you mentioned in your original question, or is it just theoretical?

Comment: Just a theoretical question before I go ahead and update the solution with ClaimRow function.

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj I actually went ahead and implemented the ClaimRow function to test and posted the code. I would appreciate if you could please guide me where I am wrong? since I am not seeing expected output.